# NoMethodError on controller method Rails 5

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, nomethoderror

**Edit #2**

Here is the server log when I click the tick

```
Started PUT "/course_modules/module-1-understanding-email-marketing-basics/complete" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-19 16:29:42 +0100
Processing by CourseModulesUsersController#complete as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"CfIM56PhiIRumytV99CE7GFK6tYumCgDvBwUS79jhbCr3zpXLfbJgvqUFkzwmKLXQiOxk1SmFvGoO4+M1z87wg==", "id"=>"module-1-understanding-email-marketing-basics"}
  CourseModulesUser Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "course_modules_users".* FROM "course_modules_users" WHERE "course_modules_users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 0], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/course_modules_users_controller.rb:3
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)



NoMethodError (undefined method `complete=' for nil:NilClass):

app/controllers/course_modules_users_controller.rb:4:in `complete'
```

**Edit #1**

So here is where I'm at now.

I can access the records using the rails console

```
irb(main):017:0> @course_modules_users = CourseModulesUser.find_by(id: 1)
  CourseModulesUser Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "course_modules_users".* FROM "course_modules_users" WHERE "course_modules_users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<CourseModulesUser id: 1, course_module_id: 1, courses_user_id: 1, complete: false, created_at: "2018-09-19 13:04:16", updated_at: "2018-09-19 14:58:17">
irb(main):018:0> @course_modules_users.complete = true
=> true
```

If I try to check based on the boolean value like this

```
<% if @course_modules_users.where(complete: true).nil? %>
  <i class="fas fa-check text-green float-left mr-1"></i>
  <span class="text-xs mr-2">Completed</span>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to complete_course_module_path(course_module), method: :put do %>
  <i class="fas fa-check text-grey-darkest float-left mr-2"></i>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The show as

[image]

But if I manually change a record

[image]

nothing changes on the front-end

[image]

**Original**

Here is my error:

[image]

So I currently have a route setup that once clicked triggers the following `complete` method with changes the record to true. However, as you can see it can't find the complete method.

Here is the database

[image: database]

I have tested this in the terminal and it can find the complete field

[image: termial]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that `@course_modules_user` is **nil**, noting wrong with the `complete` method. So you have defined

```
@course_modules_user = CourseModulesUser.find_by(id: params[:id])
```

Check the `params` and make sure you have a record with `params[:id]` value in the `course_modules_users` table, so that `@course_modules_user` is not nil.

**Update:**

As you are using `friendly_id`, the value of `id` sent as `slug`. So tell Rails not to by changing the `link_to` like so

```
<%= link_to complete_course_module_path(course_module.id), method: :put do %>
```

Comment: I'd amend CourseModulesUser.find_by(id: params[:id]) to CourseModulesUser.find!(params[:id]) so that it raises a 404 error if the object isn't found.

Comment: @B.J.B Update the question with the `params` that appear in the server log when you click the link to complete the `course_module`

Comment: See edit #2 it seems to be using the friendly_id slug and not the numeric id

Comment: @B.J.B Are you using `friendly_id`?

Comment: I am, but obviously, I want to use the id not the slug

Comment: @B.J.B Ok, try changing `<%= link_to complete_course_module_path(course_module), method: :put do %>` to `<%= link_to complete_course_module_path(course_module.id), method: :put do %>`

Comment: Ah, that worked, awesome. However, the ticks still don't change based on the boolean value!

Comment: @B.J.B Thats another problem which is unrelated to the current problem. I will update my answer with the changes,so you can mark it as accepted. Btw, you can always post a question explaining the problem.